# Using multiple fields in MySQL LIKE operator

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, python-3.8

I want to create a **search bar** in ***python***. The search bar will search records from  table of **MySQL** database. Table has ***9 fields***. I want that search bar searches from all the 9 fields and show the result. But I can use only 2 fields at most.

```
command = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 or field2 LIKE '%PARAM%"
```

I Want something like this...

```
command = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 or field2 or field3 or field4 or field5 LIKE '%PARAM%"
```

**But multiple or's are not supported in SQL commands**

So is there any way I can search from every field using **LIKE** Operator

Comment: `Field1 like '%'  OR field2 like '%' OR...` ...  Use SQL parameter to not repeat

Comment: The request you are asking for above is not too common in SQL.  Having the need to check for the same value across so many might indicate a design smell.  You may include your table definition above if you wish.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it makes sense as a 'free text search' across multiple fields.

Comment: I'm worried about the possibility of SQL injection in this scenario,  make sure you take it into account!

Answer (score 1):

You could just concatenate them

```
command = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE concat(field1, field2, field3, field4, field5) LIKE '%PARAM%"
```

You may want to join them with some separator to reduce the possibility of collisions.

```
command = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE concat_ws('|', field1, field2, field3, field4, field5) LIKE '%PARAM%"
```

Comment: Field1 ends with 'pro' and field2 starts with 'blem'  and we are searching for 'problem' and we have problem... Edit: not with edited

Comment: @Selvin see edit.  it still fails for 'PROB|LEM' = 'PROB','LEM', but For a search bar I don't think this would normally need to be 100%... call it a feature!